# Numpy np.where condition with multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [0, 1, 1, 1,1, 0],
                     "col2": [False, True, False, False, True, False]
                     })

data
```

I'm trying to create a column `col3` where `col1=1` and `col2==True` its **1** else **0**

Using `np.where`:

```
data.assign(col3=np.where(data["col1"]==1 & data["col2"], 1, 0))
```

```
col1    col2    col3
0   0   False   1
1   1   True    1
2   1   False   0
3   1   False   0
4   1   True    1
5   0   False   1
```

For row 1: col1==0 & col2=False, but I'm getting col3 as 1.

What am I missing??

The desired output:

```
col1    col2    col3
0   0   False   0
1   1   True    1
2   1   False   0
3   1   False   0
4   1   True    1
5   0   False   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing parentheses (`&` has higher [precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than `==`):

```
data.assign(col3=np.where((data["col1"]==1) & data["col2"], 1, 0))
```

A way to avoid this is to use [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html):

```
data.assign(col3=np.where(data["col1"].eq(1) & data["col2"], 1, 0))
```

You can also replace the `numpy.where` by `astype`:

```
data.assign(col3=((data["col1"]==1) & data["col2"]).astype(int))
```

Output:

```
   col1   col2  col3
0     0  False     0
1     1   True     1
2     1  False     0
3     1  False     0
4     1   True     1
5     0  False     0
```